# how to configure a redhat linux server as a webserver for hosting websites?

Tags: webserver, redhat

I have an IBM server (system x3250m4) and i have installed Linux red hat 6 server edition.

Now i need to make it as a web server for hosting websites via ftp.  So i want to know what are all the procedures needed to make it as a web server. can anyone help me to resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use "ISPConfig"

including : web server, ftp server, mysql databaes, emails, dns

link to build your hosting server : [Perfect Server Fedora 15](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-fedora-15-x86_64-ispconfig-3)

Comment: OK sir. Thank you for your reply.before that i need to know that how to add windows clients to my Linux server to provide permission and all controls to the limited client users.